# Laravel illluminati collection remove duplicate item

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I have a collection called **$applied_exams** which contain following data

```
Collection {#2033 ▼#items: array:4 [▼
0 => {#2035 ▼
  +"post_id": 1
  +"designation_id": 9
  +"token_number": 438
  +"name": "TECHNICIAN TELECOM"
  +"adb": "2074-06-23"
  +"ContainMultiplePost": false
  +"Group_id": 8
}
1 => {#2034 ▼
  +"post_id": 11
  +"designation_id": 1
  +"token_number": 740
  +"name": "DEPUTY MANAGER TELECOM"
  +"adb": "2074-06-25"
  +"ContainMultiplePost": false
  +"Group_id": 1
}
2 => {#2040 ▼
  +"post_id": 3
  +"designation_id": 12
  +"token_number": 2810
  +"name": "ASST. BUSINESS OFFICER"
  +"adb": "2074-10-24"
  +"ContainMultiplePost": true
  +"Group_id": 7
}
3 => {#2039 ▼
  +"post_id": 2
  +"designation_id": 8
  +"token_number": 2811
  +"name": "ASST. ADMINISTRATIVE OFFICER"
  +"adb": "2074-10-24"
  +"ContainMultiplePost": true
  +"Group_id": 7
}]}
```

I want to unset the data with duplicate group_id. I only want one data of one group_id. In this case I just want the $applied_exam[3] to be removed because group_id is same as $applied_exams[2]. Please help. Thanks

Comment: add what you have done so far, your logic to get this data

Comment: the answer  $collection->unique('group_id'); worked, thanks for your concern

Comment: @Rox you shouldn't use `unique` in this case, it's a bad idea. You should construct a query which will get unique records instead of loading everything and then removing duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [unique](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-unique) function

```
$unique_applied_exams = $applied_exams->unique('group_id');
```